# Application or Object defined error in For loop

Tags: vba, excel

So i'm getting an

> application-defined or object-defined error

and I really can't figure out why. My for loop ran fine when `j=1` but when `j=2` it broke. Basically what i'm trying to do is this:

I have a stored value from another sheet "material" I want it to look on a separate sheet, find that value in column D and store the information in columns A and B. I want it to stop searching after it finds the first occurance, which is why I put the if check = true in there.

Can anyone help me figure out this error?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")
j = 0
Set ProcCell = .Range("D2")
    numproc = .Range("C2", .Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Do While check = False
            For j = 1 To numproc
                If check = True Then Exit For
                If ProcCell.Offset(-j, 0).value = Material Then
                    procStaticID = ProcCell.Offset(-i, -3).value
                    firstInstructionID = ProcCell.Offset(-i, -2).value
                    check = True
                End If
            Next j
        Loop
End With
```

Comment: If you start in the second row `ProcCell.Offset(-j, 0)` will obviously fail as soon as `j` hits 2 since there is no row which is two rows above the second row.

Comment: Which line errors out?

Comment: oh wow i'm stupid... I was thinking negative was down.. thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @BrendanKelley :)